# Source port and destination port

Tags: ports, wireshark

Just fiddling with `wireshark` and telegram as part of some learning exercise on security.

I realised that the source port for the telegram app is 58939 and the destination port would be 443.

Why is that so? Is it even possible to port forward the packets to port 443 from my telegram app to `fiddler` which can decrypt https packets?

Answer (score 1):

58939 is one of the '[ephemeral ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)' these are used for specific connections between client and server so only 1 of the ports is limited (the destination) and not 2 (even besides the fact that 443 is below the 1024 Root only limit of ports)

your second question is one of not understanding your tools. fiddler can be operated as a proxy. so you can do this 'intercept' simply by configuring your proxy. (a.k.a. a classic case of not following the ancient wisdom of '[RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)'